# Need Help giving sprite node button an animation while it is being pressed

Tags: ios, swift, animation, skspritenode

I'm sure I sound like a completed noob but I'm working on my first iOS game and it includes a shoot button which is an arcade style button that I would like to animate by swapping to the "shootPressed" image while the user holds it down then swaps back when released.
Here I have my touches began, moved, and ended. Keep in my mind I left out any nonconflicting code. I've been stuck on this problem for the last two days.

UPDATE: I've included the function I used for creating my button node

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in:self)
        let node = self.atPoint(location)

        if(node.name == "Shoot") {
            shootButton.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shootPushed")
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in:self)
        let node = self.atPoint(location)
        if (node.name == "Shoot") {
            shootBeams()
            shootButton.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shootUnpushed" )
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in:self)
        let node = self.atPoint(location)
        if node.name == ("shoot") {
            shootButton.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shootPushed")
        }
    }
}    

func addButtons() {
        var buttonT1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shootUnpushed")
        var buttonT2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shootPushed")

        var shootButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: buttonT1)                        
        shootButton.name = "Shoot"
        shootButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX - 130, y: leftButton.position.y)
        shootButton.zPosition = 7
        shootButton.size = CGSize(width: shootButton.size.width*0.2, height: shootButton.size.height*0.2)
        self.addChild(shootButton)
 }
```

Comment: Could you show the setup-code for the buttonNode?

Comment: here you go thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `shootButton` you create in  `addButtons` is a local variable.

So, when you do `shootButton.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shootPushed")` inside the touchesMoved this is certainly not referring to the same node.

As this apparently compiles this would mean that you already have a property `shootButton` in the class. The problem would most likely be fixed if you change the `var shootButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: buttonT1)` in you `addButtons` function.

It should simply initialize the `shootButton`-property rather than creating a new *local* variable:

```
func addButtons() {
        shootButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: buttonT1)    
        shootButton.name = "Shoot"
        shootButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX - 130, y: leftButton.position.y)
        shootButton.zPosition = 7
        shootButton.size = CGSize(width: shootButton.size.width*0.2, height: shootButton.size.height*0.2)
        self.addChild(shootButton) 
}
```

Comment: I altered my code to initialize my shoot button properly but it remains on my "shootUnpressed" image when pressed, could it be how I went about changing my texture in my touchesBegan, touchesEnded, or touchesMoved?

Comment: Well, your `touchesMoved` probably won't change the texture at all, since your checking the name match agains "shoot" rather than "Shoot" but `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` seems sound, as long as the assets actually look correct.

Comment: Could it be that you mix up "Shoot" and "shoot" more places? String comparison is about as error-prone as anything gets...

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much I can't believe I never picked up on that!